# Will OS linked to your microsoft account to transfer to another pc, be saved to cloud

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

Hi I did some research and found out that I could link my microsoft account so that when I make drastic changes to my pc, I can still reinstall the OS i have (Windows 10 pro). In the sites of people doing this, they all have changed motherboards, CPU, but didn't change their hdd or sdd. Here's my problem. I wanted to know if the OS linked to my account become saved to cloud so that even if I even change my whole pc entirely, If I link my account, I can reinstall OS on that new pc. I have this problem because I am changing my motherboard,CPU,RAM,graphics card, and hdd/sdd. Please ask any questions.

Comment: No; It doesn’t;

Comment: @Ramhound do you have any proofs that it won't work after changing hardvare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a linkage to Microsoft account and it work's nicely.

I can not make a screenshot right now from that PC but it's linked.
According to docs it must work on new PC with same account. According to [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-link-your-windows-10-product-key-microsoft-account) instruction.

Furthermore, I've just tested my MS account and found interesting fact. I've recently upgraded my PC. I've changed CPU, RAM count and Graphics card. On first I only changed CPU. Now Microsoft thinks I have two PC. But it didn't detect one with new CPU and old Graphis.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

License is typically locked to either CPU/Bios, HDD (serial number) or NIC Mac address.

Hard to say if you can choose which it uses.

You can try emailing MS Support and see if they can lock as needed.

If it's a purchased license, you should be able to reinstall using the Install key.